# Why does the rig generate below my mesh?

Tags: rigging

Need help with generating a rig. It generates below the mesh.

[image]

Comment: adding at least some detail about how are you generating the rig would help, perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

In Object mode, select your mesh and apply (Ctrl A) location, rotation and scale, do the same with the generator rig, then generate.